# How to show posts in browse only from current authenticated user/author in Voyager?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I need to display in the Browse option of Voyager the posts only from the user that is logged in in the web. Posts from other users should be hidden. Do I need to make other controller for this or edit the voyagerbreadcontroller.php query based in authenticated user?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hey did you achieved this? If so can you share some infos?

Answer (score 0):

**This works:**

**Add to `register` method of `AppServiceProvider.php`:**

```
$this->app->bind('TCG\Voyager\Models\Post', function ($app) {
    return new App\Post;
});
```

**Create the new model that extends Voyager's model, and use a conditional addGlobalScope:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use TCG\Voyager\Models\Post as VoyagerPost;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Post extends VoyagerPost
{
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

                // Customize your own rule here!
        if (\Request::is('management/*') && Auth::user()->canBlogSolo()) { 
            static::addGlobalScope('author', function (Builder $builder) {
                $builder->where('author_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share more info?